# dlls: static vs implicit linking, same thing?

Tags: c++, dll

Concerning Dll linkage, are static and implicit linking the same thing?

I understand the difference between implicit and explicit linking, and I think static is synonymous with implicit, but am not certain.

if they are indeed different, what is the difference between them, and how do I specify which one I want?

this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yd93633%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) from msft uses the term "implicit" for what I've heard referred to as "static". Is it perhaps a msft-specific thing?

Comment: Where did you hear the term "implicit linking"? I've not heard of it yet.

Comment: @Nawaz [here's an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yd93633%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) from M$ that suggests it's the proper terminology. maybe it's a M$ vs. everybody else difference? Not sure. That's why I'm asking, because I think they're the same thing.

Comment: Oh I see. The msdn link explains the terms well enough. So I wonder what is your doubt now?

Comment: @ash You should icnorporate that link into the question, it's not everyday terminology.

Comment: @ash:  `Implicit linking is sometimes referred to as static load or load-time dynamic linking. Explicit linking is sometimes referred to as dynamic load or run-time dynamic linking.`  The first sentence there answered your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in Windows-land, when discussing linking to DLLs, the terms *static linking* and *implicit linking* are synonymous.

The [Visual Studio documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yd93633.aspx) calls this out:

> Implicit linking is sometimes referred to as static load or load-time dynamic linking. Explicit linking is sometimes referred to as dynamic load or run-time dynamic linking.

In days gone by Microsoft preferred the terms *implicit* and *explicit* linking. Nowadays they seem to prefer the terms [*load-time* and *run-time*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681914.aspx), respectively. All the same, when people talk about linking to DLLs, the term *static* means is synonymous with *implicit* and *load-time*.

I for one try to avoid using *static* in relation to DLL linking for a couple of reasons:

1. It's easy to get mixed up with linking to a static library.
2. The idea that one might link statically to something that is dynamic just feels oxymoronic.
3. The term static is already used to mean who knows how many different things in the C and C++ languages and I'd rather not overload the term any more than it already is!

Answer (score 2):

Implicit linking could be done with static (.a) or dynamic libraries (.so, .dll). When you compile a program with link to the library, it's an implicit linking. It's faster thant an explicit linking.

An explicit linking is when you use `dlopen` with dynamic libraries (.so, .dll). You don't compile the program with the link to the library, but you use `dlopen` to open the file, and you extract the functions you need.

Comment: +1. The Windows quirk here is that a DLL comes with a static library (.lib); you link to the static library, and that provides the hooks for calls into the DLL. I gather that's what's meant by "implicit" linking. Sigh.

Comment: @PeteBecker I sympathise with your sigh. I find the whole idea that you can link *statically* to a *dynamic-link library* to be a complete oxymoron.