# Misconception about static/implicit linking Vs dynamic/explcit linking

Tags: c++, windows, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I've recently learnt that static linking and implicit linking are [basically the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731158/dlls-static-vs-implicit-linking-same-thing), just different nomenclature. My understanding is that when you statically (implicitely) link to a binary, you are by definition linking against a `*.lib` (windows) or `*.a` (linux) file, often using `target_link_libraries` in cmake. On the other hand when you explicitely link (using `LoadLibrary` on windows) you are by definition linking to a `*.dll` file (or `*.so` on linux) (and there is no corresponding cmake command because all the work is done inside the actual code).

However, in [multiple places](http://barngoggles.com/a-bunch-of-words-test-post-2/) I've read people referring to statically/implicitely linking to a `dll` file, which has confused me. Clearly there is a hole in my knowledge somewhere and I was hoping somebody here could plug it.

## Edit

Its been pointed out that this question refers mainly to windows, which it does. However, I am currently trying to produce cross platform code so I am still interested on how (or if) these concepts generalise to other platforms.

Comment: These things differ for different operating systems.

Comment: Linking to the `.dll` happens when you are using .NET / CLR in native executables `c++` you link to the import library or use a `.def` or directly use LoadLibrary

Comment: If these things differ for different operating systems, does it even make sense to try and write a cross platform shared library using cmake?

Comment: ***does it even make sense to try and write a cross platform shared library using cmake?*** Yes. You may want to look at the Kitware software like `itk` how they handle building shared libraries on different platforms. And before you convert your codebase to cross platform try small example projects first.

Comment: Using runtime dynamic linking lets you control the DLL search path via `SetDefaultDllDirectories` and `AddDllDirectory`, which is more secure than the default DLL search path with load-time linking, which includes the working directory and `PATH`.  But linking manually via `LoadLibraryExW` and `GetProcAddress` is tedious since you have to specify function prototypes for the compiler to generate the right code. Windows has a better way: [delayed loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually 3 different kinds of linking, not 2.

For UNIX:

1. Link against archive (aka static) library:

   `gcc main.o libfoo.a`
2. link against dynamic (aka shared) library:

   `gcc main.o libfoo.so`
3. Link against `libdl`, which allows you to `dlopen` arbitrary other shared libraries (which don't need to exist at the time of the link):

   `gcc main.o -ldl`

Both 2 and 3 involve dynamic linker (and are using shared libraries), but to a different extent.

An equivalent exists on Windows: when you link against `foo.lib`, you are using *either* 1 or 2, depending on whether `foo.lib` contains actual code, or refers to `foo.dll`.

When you use `LoadLibrary`, you are in case 3.